# Form Submission via an a href tag not working

Tags: jquery, html, forms

In our app, we recently adopted an improved GUI style.  Originally, our form submit links were similar to the following:

```
<input type=submit class="some-style" name="Command" value="Save" />
```

However, we're trying to use the following instead:

```
<input id='hiddenSaver' type="hidden" name="Command" value="Save" />
<a id='saveButton' href="#" class="some-style"><i class="some-icon"></i> Save</a>

<!-- SNIP: Extraneous other stuff -->

<script>
var $saveButton = $('saveButton'),
    $hiddenSaver = $('hiddenSaver');

$(document).ready(function () {
  $saveButton.click(function () {
    $saveButton.preventDefault();
    $hiddenSaver.submit();
  });
});
</script>
```

Yet our forms do not submit...in fact, they just don't do anything.  What are we missing?

Comment: use `.submit()` on form not button

Comment: You could drop the JavaScript completely if you used `<button type="submit">`.

Comment: Per accepted answer, chose a different methodology altogether.  While continuing to use `<a href>` is certainly a viable strategy, the situation my team is in is more suited for using `<button>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `.submit()` on an input field not a form. Below is an excerpt from the jQuery documentation:

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form. It can only be attached to `<form>` elements. Forms can be submitted either by clicking an explicit `<input type="submit">`, `<input type="image">`, or `<button type="submit">`, or by pressing Enter when certain form elements have focus.

Refer to the jQuery API page for `.submit()` here:

[jQuery .Submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Try attaching the `.submit()` to the form you're submitting. Also take not of what inputs, they recommend for submitting a form. I'm not sure if you can do it with your anchor tag. You could certainly use:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

I know you are using a new GUI but with some CSS styling you could get the button to look pretty nice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doing: `<button type="submit" class="some-class">...</button>` worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewGray, in all fairness to future readers, what does using `<button>` have to do with your original question: _"Submission via an a href tag"_?  Also, this answer missed the other problems with your code.

Comment: @Sparky I think he was merely pointing out the input he used in place of an `href` to submit the form as referenced in the blockquote above.

Comment: He clearly stated that he's _"trying to use the following instead"_  ... pointing to an `<a id='saveButton' href="#"` tag that is specifically targeted by his jQuery.

Comment: @Sparky `trying to use`. He tried. It didn't work out so he's using a button. My apologies I wasn't trying to pick a fight. I was simply pointing out that the op tried to use a `<a>` and after reading the article decided to use a `<button>` instead because it worked for him. Altering the question to reflect the use of the `<button>` input would render all the answers invalid as they would no longer pertain to the original question.

Comment: I'm certainly not suggesting the OP alter the question at this late stage, nor do I wish a fight with anyone.  I'm only suggesting that the OP more fairly accept an answer that solves his question as he posted it, instead of picking a whole new methodology.  It doesn't always work out like that, but it's good for future readers to see comments that explain what happened.  Carry on.

Comment: @Sparky: No insult taken.  While the original plan was to _make_ `<a href>` work, using `<button>` worked out much more cleanly, and along the lines of what we're intending.  This was a case where a change of methodology worked better than sticking with one that was more challenging.

I didn't wish to offend anyone by accepting _this_ answer; this answer merely solved my problem best of all.  I appreciate everyone who posted a response; if nothing else I learned that you submit forms, not inputs (and a few ways of doing just that, to boot.)

Comment: @Sparky I see where you are coming from. My apologies for the misunderstanding. I'm glad you got it resolved Andrew. Best of luck and happy coding to you both.

Answer (score 1):

You are not correctly using [**id selector**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and missed the `#` before id in selector.

```
var $saveButton = $('#saveButton'),
$hiddenSaver = $('#hiddenSaver');
```

Call submit on form object not on button

```
$hiddenSaver.closest('form').submit();
```

Or

```
$hiddenSaver = $('hiddenSaver').closest("form");
$hiddenSaver.submit();
```

Comment: There's no reason to wrap the `$hiddenSaver` to `$()` again when calling `.submit()`. It's already a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

This answer fully solves the original question as posted including a working demo...

> **Title**:  "Submission via an a href tag"

Several issues with your code as follows...

1) Your jQuery ID selectors were missing the `#` sign.

2) You failed to pass the event variable `e` to `.preventDefault()` using `function(e)` and `e.preventDefault()`

3) `submit()` gets attached to the `form` itself, not an `input` element.

I corrected your code below:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id='hiddenSaver' type="hidden" name="Command" value="Save" />
</form>

<a id='saveButton' href="#" class="some-style"><i class="some-icon"></i> Save</a>

<!-- SNIP: Extraneous other stuff -->

<script>
var $saveButton = $('#saveButton'),
    $hiddenSaver = $('#hiddenSaver'),
    $myform = $('#myform');

$(document).ready(function() {
    $saveButton.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $myform.submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

**Working Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/sBueS/

I included the jQuery Validate plugin in the jsFiddle only to prove that the form is indeed submitted using the `submit()` event triggered by the anchor tag `<a>`.

Comment: Eep!  Didn't realize I'd left the # out on the original post.  Rest assured, they are there in the actual code.

Comment: @AndrewGray, my post directly answers your question about how to use an anchor tag to submit a form.  It's also the only answer that identifies all three problems with the posted code.

Comment: On the one hand, I agree completely; that being said, it's edged out by the `<button>` as it's more compact (and we had to roll back some code to our old way before consulting StackOverflow).  The intent was not to be unfair in selecting an answer, just to select the answer that solved my given problem.